# Why is there a [poodle-attack] tag?

Tags: discussion

It seems to me that most of the questions in [poodle-attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poodle-attack) (21 at the time of writing) are asking how to disable SSLv3. For this there is no need for a specific tag. Many of the questions also seem to be better suited for [SecSE](https://security.stackexchange.com/). Some time there is already a duplicate question on SecSE.

There are a lot of questions because of it, but does this justify the tag since it doesn't really add anything meaningful to the questions.

I think that [ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssl) and [sslv3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sslv3) are more appropriate since they show *what* this is about not *why* this is an interesting question.

<sup>I guess the same applies to [heartbleed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heartbleed), but I didn't check the questions.</sup>

Comment: I once heard from a wise man, "There are *always* poodles."

Comment: The larger ones tend to be docile, adorable and well-behaved, but the smaller ones are so high strung that they just atta... oh, wait.

Answer (score 1):

What would the appropriate tag be?  It's ok to not like a tag; but be prepared to suggest a better alternative.

Comment: The common [ssl] or even [sslv3] is good enough. SecSE also doesn't have one.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I don't currently see any questions tagged [poodle], so...

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I just looked as well- There _is_ a [poodle-attack] with 21 questions... But no [poodle]

Comment: Somebody renamed it just now.